# NextSibling with class not working

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

This is my code and it's not alerting anything and nor is it returning anything good :(
the first part works fine
but afterwords it doesnt :( i cant seem to figure out what the problem is..

```
   this.getNextItem = function(o) {
// given <li> playlist item, find next <li> and then <a>

  if (o.nextElementSibling) {
      o = o.nextElementSibling;
    } 
    else {

      o = o.nextSibling;

  }


    while (o && o.className !== 'playerr') {
       if (o.nextElementSibling) {
             o = o.nextElementSibling;

             } else {

                o = o.nextSibling;

             }

       }

   if(o){ if (o.className !== 'playerr') { //nodeName.toLowerCase()


          return null;
    } else {
         alert(o.className);
          alert(o.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]);
      return o.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    }}

  };
```

if you want to see the full context its http://beastdrops.com then run page("content2") in consol to get to the new "player" 
forward the song to the end then when its about to change to the next one it will not... :( thats what this script has to do

Comment: You're not running any tests to see if `o` is an object. `while (o && o.getAttribute('class') !== 'playerr') {` ...and... `if (o) {if (o.getAttribute('class') !== 'playerr') { ... } else { ... } }`

Comment: does the sibling of the element `o` passed as a parameter have a `class` attribute? (i.e. always?)

Comment: ...also, use `o.className` instead of `.getAttribute("class")`

Comment: ...and indent your code evenly. It's sort of a mess right now.

Comment: it doesnt have a class always going to update the code: how it looks currently

Comment: If it doesn't have a class, why are you testing for its class? Anyway, the issue is likely the lack of tests for `o`. You should be checking your developer console for errors. Here's an updated version of the code. http://jsfiddle.net/Y4CtM/

Comment: You've really got to learn to indent your code cleanly. No one wants to read code that looks like that.

Comment: how should it look? 
im sorry for beeing messy but i got used to seeing code as such

Comment: @KolosFeriFazekas - try pasting your code in here: http://jsbeautifier.org/ to see what nice, compact, readable code that many people are used to looks like.

Comment: thanks! The script still doesnt work :( if you want to see the full context its http://beastdrops.com then run page("content2") in consol to get to the new "player" forward the song to the end then when its about to change to the next one it will not... :( thats what this script has to do

Answer (score 5):

OK, per your comments, it looks like you want to do `nextByClass()` so here's a version that does that:

```
function hasClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    var testCls = " " + cls + " ";
    return(str.indexOf(testCls) != -1) ;
}

function nextByClass(node, cls) {
    while (node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (hasClass(node, cls)) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3L9FL/

You could use this to find the next item on the same level with the desired class like this:

```
// assumes you pass it the node for the starting <li>
// returns first link in next <li> with the desired classor null if none
this.getNextItem = function(node) {
    node = nextByClass(node, "playerr");
    if (node) {
        return node.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Older version of answer superceded by clarification in comments:

Per the comments in your code, it looks like given an element that is an `<li>` tag, you just want to find the next `<li>` on the same level.  If that's the case, here's a very simple function that finds the next sibling of the same tagName:

```
// gets the next sibling with the same tagName as the starting point
// returns null if none found
function nextByTag(node) {
    var tag = node.tagName;
    while (node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.tagName === tag) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

You could use this to find the first descendant link in the next `<li>` like this:

```
// assumes you pass it the node for the starting <li>
// returns first link in next <li> or null if none
this.getNextItem = function(node) {
    node = nextByTag(node);
    if (node) {
        return node.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to work for :( in my case since the main problem is that the next node is not good for me only about the 6th with the class of playerr :( if you want to see the full code http://beastdrops.com and in console run page("content2")
there press play after waiting abit (its a bit buggy) and then go to the end of the music and then it the getNextItem will try to run..
its ment to start playing the music below it

Comment: @KolosFeriFazekas - OK.  Per your clarification, I've added a version to the beginning of the answer that works by class name.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D9JhW/1/ it seems like next sibling doesnt go ahead of some divs and other tags:S

Comment: @KolosFeriFazekas - your HTML in that jsFiddle is pretty messed up and completely unreadable too (horrible indentation).  You can't just insert an `<li>` tag in the middle of some `<div>` tags.  An `<li>` needs to be in the correct container (a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`) and only have other `<li>` tags as siblings. When you've made your HTML into legal HTML, then you will have to describe what you're really trying to do because your current structure can't be searched with nextSibling at all.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  From what element do you want to find what?

Comment: @KolosFeriFazekas - You perhaps don't understand what `nextSibling` actually does.  It finds the next tag with the same immediate parent at the same level of the hierarchy.  It does not go beyond that.